# Sidekiq + ActiveJob callbacks run too fast

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I use Sidekiq with ActiveJob and its callbacks. At the beginning I'd like to say that my problem sounds very similar to this one: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Problems-and-Troubleshooting#cannot-find-modelname-with-id12345 however I don't use ActiveRecord callbacks.

I have a service having the method like this:

```
def call
  array_of_batches.each do |batch|
    MyJob.perform_later(batch)
  end
end
```

Which means it creates many jobs that are performed concurrently. In the job I use `before_perform` and `after_perform` callbacks and I have 2 problems with each of them.

1:

```
before_perform do |job|
  # do something
  return if my_object.status == 'performed'
  my_object.update(status: 'performed')
  send_notification
end
```

In the case above it often happens that when a few jobs are running concurrently I send a notification a few times instead of only one. In a few jobs it goes to the end instead of only once in a first job that is run.

2:

```
after_perform do |job|
  my_object.decrement!(:count)
  return unless my_object.count.zero?
  my_object.update(status: 'finished')
  send_notification
end
```

In the case above it happens that decrementing is not on time and because of that the object status is not updated correctly and a notification is never sent. For example when the `count` value before performing 10 jobs equals `10` then after performing all the jobs `count` attribute equals `2` or `3` instead of `0` since we were supposed to decrement the value every single time.

Is it possible to fix those cases somehow?
Cheers

Comment: Can you try to reload `my_object` before updating it? I guess your code is not thread-safe.

Comment: Yeah I tried but it didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: you could use a mutex to synchronize your threads. i consider this an antipattern though. it's usually more efficient to split tasks into atomic pieces and execute the pieces in parallel. the resulting code is usually a lot easier to understand and maintain as it has no timing issues.